# How to remove timezone from datetime object?

Tags: python, postgresql, datetime, async-await

My task is to convert datetime to utc without timezone information before storing to DataBase. So I do:

```
async def post(payload: InvoiceSchema):
    dt = payload.timestamp
    dt = dt.astimezone(timezone.utc)
    dt.replace(tzinfo=None)

    query = invoices.insert().values(
        merchant_name=payload.merchant_name,
        amount=payload.amount,
        timestamp=dt
    )
    return await database.execute(query=query)
```

But I still have an error

```
asyncpg.exceptions.DataError: invalid input for query argument $3: datetime.datetime(2020, 4, 20, 8, 
12, 12... (can't subtract offset-naive and offset-aware datetimes)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

YOu need to assign the dt.replace to a new variable:

```
In [8]: dt = datetime.now()
   ...: dt = dt.astimezone(timezone.utc)
   ...: dt1= dt.replace(tzinfo=None)

In [9]: dt1
Out[9]: datetime.datetime(2020, 4, 19, 12, 59, 56, 439648)

In [10]: dt
Out[10]: datetime.datetime(2020, 4, 19, 12, 59, 56, 439648, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc)
```